# In multi-threads program,malloc() is locked exclusively

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, malloc

Linux kernel 2.6.34

In multi-threads program,when each thread uses `malloc()` at the same time,an application performance get down.That's because each thread is locked exclusively in `malloc()`.

To avoid this problem,I'm thinking that `mallopt()` can be used.

For this collision,

Usage of `mallopt()` like below is correct?

```
mallopt(M_ARENA_MAX,8);
```

Also,what is *default* arena max size?

Comment: usually, people in your situation just use `tcmalloc`

Comment: Is it impossible that this problem is  resolved only with glibc?

Comment: you should explain why you want to stick with glibc, maybe you will unveil something related to your problem that can be useful to who wants to suggest another option.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [gperftools](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/), which has a multi-threaded malloc (tcmalloc).

It gives each thread a small thread-local cache for allocating small (<32k) objects from.